# метод возращает внутренний обьект по ссылке

Tags: c++

```
class Base
{
public:
  vector<T>&get();
private:
  vector<T> _m;
}
```

Предоставляя вектор getter'ом чую, что нарушаю инкапсуляцию. Дайте оценку правомерности?

Comment: Зависит от того, чего вы добиваетесь. Формально — да, нужно работать через интерфейс, не дающий такой полноценный доступ к внутреннему устройству. Но и задачи, и методы их решения бывают разные. Жесткий догматизм не очень хорош — "железной рукой загоним человечество к счастью", так сказать :)

Comment: Геттер именно это и должен делать. Инкапсуляция бы нарушалась, если бы поле `_m` было публичным, а так внутреннее устройство класса от пользователей остается скрыто.

Comment: Не должен ли быть константным геттер?

Answer (score 6):

> чую, что нарушаю инкапсуляцию

Меньше думайте про умные термины. Любое усложенение в коде должно быть оправдано какой-то практической необходимостью. Почему не

```
struct Base
{
    vector<T> m;
};
```

?

Ответ "потому что инкапсуляция" - глупость, если вы не понимаете, какая от этого польза на практике.

Иногда отвечают "а вдруг я (за)хочу проверять вектор перед записью в класс?". Тогда ваш стиль геттера не поможет, потому что вы не сможете проверить, что пишут в вектор. Зато сработало бы так:

```
void SetM(std::vector<T> new_m) {m = std::move(new_m);}
const std::vector<T> &GetM() const {return m;}
```

А если такие проверки не нужны и не понадобятся в будущем, то лучше сделать поле публичным и все.

Я только один раз видел, чтобы пригождался сеттер, возвращающий неконстантную ссылку - в системе undo/redo, которая перед изменением поля сохраняла старое значение. Но это какой-то очень редкий случай.

Answer (score 3):

Раз уж пошла дискуссия...

Depends on, так сказать. Именно такой, как у вас, геттер позволяет влезть внутрь и бесконтрольно чудить что угодно. А если, например, инвариант класса требует какую-нибудь нормированность вектора или что еще? Именно поэтому я и говорил в комментарии, что зависит от того, какая решается задача. Грубо говоря, насколько можно/нужно/*безопасно* пустить внешнего наблюдателя внутрь.

Например, вектор — это просто коэффициенты квадратного уравнения (или какого-то полинома), для которого ищутся корни или что еще. Тогда такой геттер вполне оправдан, поскольку одним легким движением руки задается все, что нужно, и на него не наложены какие-то ограничения.

Если этот вектор предназначен для внутреннего хранения, особенно если на него наложены какие-то инварианты класса, но в каких-то ситуациях он нужен пользователю весь как выходная информация — ну что ж, можно и так, но с обязательным добавлением волшебного слова `const` (или возвратом копии, например, хотя навскидку придумать, где это лучше ссылки на константный вектор, не могу).

И уж совсем это не нужно, если этот вектор внутри — особенность реализации. И, например, в какой-то момент в будущем будет добавлена какая-то функциональность, которая эффективно реализуется, например, с помощью дека. А всё, уже нельзя: вы уже сообщили всем, что у вас там внутри вектор, и раз он выглядывает наружу — все, деком ему не стать.

Внешний интерфейс — очень неповоротливая вещь, монумент, который надо продумывать не менее тщательно, чем используемые алгоритмы, например...